# How to edit Magento's API function "items()" to get the ImageUrl of the product

Tags: php, android, magento

I am trying to get the **Image URL** of the products by editing the **Magento's API** `items() function`. I have used `$product-> getImageUrl()` to get the **URL** but I am getting wrong **URL**.

The **URL** that I am getting is of the **default Image** which we place for the **products** which do not have image(Image Comming Soon like Image's url).

I am calling the function from **Android Client** using **XML-RPC**.
I am getting other details of the product correct,but the **URL** that I am getting for the products is wrong. And, all the **URLs** of the different products I am getting are same.

FYI, The URL that I am getting in the response is like :

<sup>http://192.168.1.237/machinetest/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg</sup>

The function that I am editing is as followed :

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_filtersMap[$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_filtersMap[$field];
                }
                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
         //$result[] = $product->getData();
           $result[] = array( // Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
           'category_ids'=> $product->getCategoryIds(),
             'url_path'  =>  $product-> getImageUrl() // Added the Method here 
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write that please try this way..you will get the Solution on the Top

You can able to get Images using this code just go through it and you will get images

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_filtersMap[$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_filtersMap[$field];
                }

                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
//            $result[] = $product->getData();

        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $_image=$_product->getImageUrl();

        $result[] = array( // Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),

            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
           'category_ids'=> $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'image_url_path' =>  $_image
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

hope it's work
if you have any queries tell me i will help you!

Answer (score 4):

I was working with images recently and I believe I have pretty good understanding about it.

I don't think what Josua said is the "real" correct answer. It is good that his answer can solve your problem but I just couldn't stand seeing misleading information.

As for his first option, it is "correct".

Let me break down the code:

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Media_Config`

```
public function getMediaUrl($file)
{
    $file = $this->_prepareFileForUrl($file);

    if(substr($file, 0, 1) == '/') {
        return $this->getBaseMediaUrl() . $file;
    }

    return $this->getBaseMediaUrl() . '/' . $file;
}

public function getBaseMediaUrl()
{
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product';
}

protected function _prepareFileForUrl($file)
{
    return str_replace(DS, '/', $file);
}
```

As you can see, it just simply add `media/ + catalog/product + $file`.

$file is taken from database, the value will be something like `/e/x/example.jpeg`

Your uploaded product images are stored inside those folders.

Now, for the problem why `$product-> getImageUrl()` give you wrong URL is still unknown.

The code that Josua suggest for second option:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($product, $type)
    ->resize(163, 100);
```

is "almost" the same with `$product->getImageUrl()`, it just have difference in `resize`

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

```
public function getImageUrl()
{
    return (string)$this->_getImageHelper()->init($this, 'image')->resize(265);
}
```

So for his second option, it will give the same result with your old code.
I don't know why did he suggest the second option, I think he never check what is behind those functions (not a good idea as it can lead to wrong information)

When you call for `$product->getImageUrl()`, it will try to load your image from cache if it exists, if not, it will load the image from database (for the path and then will look for your correct image from media folder) and create the cache. If it is unable to find the image or an error occurred, it will get the placeholder image.

My suggestion is to check if there is an exception thrown. You need to use your old code `$product->getImageUrl()`. Open your `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php`

Then go to:

`Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`

```
public function __toString()
{
    try {
        if( $this->getImageFile() ) {
            $this->_getModel()->setBaseFile( $this->getImageFile() );
        } else {
            $this->_getModel()->setBaseFile( $this->getProduct()->getData($this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()) );
        }

        if( $this->_getModel()->isCached() ) {
            return $this->_getModel()->getUrl();
        } else {
            if( $this->_scheduleRotate ) {
                $this->_getModel()->rotate( $this->getAngle() );
            }

            if ($this->_scheduleResize) {
                $this->_getModel()->resize();
            }

            if( $this->getWatermark() ) {
                $this->_getModel()->setWatermark($this->getWatermark());
            }

            $url = $this->_getModel()->saveFile()->getUrl();
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        //put log to show error message
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        $url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->getPlaceholder());
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Put `Mage::log($e->getMessage());` to log if there is an exception thrown. Most likely your placeholder image is called because there was an exception thrown.

It is just a suggestion from me to ensure there is nothing's wrong with your image / other things as in fact you have solved your problem by directly get the image from `media/catalog/product/...`

Another correction for Josua's code:

Notice the $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

It is absolutely unnecessary since inside foreach($collection as $product), the product object will be loaded, so another load of product is unnecessary (also $product_id is undefined)

UPDATE, just fixing your code:

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','image'));
        //->addAttributeToSelect('name'); add another select, either image / small_image / thumbnail, modify it as you need

    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_filtersMap[$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_filtersMap[$field];
                }
                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
         //$result[] = $product->getData();
           $result[] = array( // Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
           'category_ids'=> $product->getCategoryIds(),
             'url_path'  =>  $product-> getImageUrl() // Added the Method here 
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @HareshChaudhary so what is the Error? Even from darshan's answer I don't see the solution. I just wanted to know what is the real problem and solution as I'm here for learning not looking for points :)

Comment: Caras Keeper : I have clearly define my problem in the Question.And about the Error, Implementing Josua's Answer gives me Null-pointer Exception on the Client Side which means the Array is not Returned to the Client at All. It means that the Code Block has some Mistake so that it's not returning it. On implementing Darshan's Answer,it gave me the URL path of the Images but of the Cache folder.On deleting the cache of the MagentoStore,new cache was created automatically and again I was getting the URL of the Image which I require to call from the Client Side.And that was what I required.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought what you meant by error is, error message from the image But what you actually meant is error from Josua's answer. And now it is very clear what's wrong with your problem, should have realize about it earlier. Your old code, is 99% correct, you can change it back to your old code, but in the collection, you should select the `image` attribute so it will be like this `->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','image'));`. I believe it is the best solution.

Comment: Caras Keeper : Can you please update all you Experience in your Answer ? What I want is all the Information in 1 call from the Client so that I will not have to call certain times to get different details of the product.Is there any mean that will achieve me this.I am a newbie to php So have problem to update the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was awesome!

Yes, you can get image url with :

```
'url_path'  =>  Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                ->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());//getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()
```

---

or another option by calling :

```
$type = 'small_image';
'url_path'  => $this->helper('catalog/image')
                   ->init($product, $type)
                   ->resize(163, 100);
```

can be changed by 'image' small_image' or 'thumbnail'

**Default:**

- Base Image: 265x265 pixel
- Small Image: 135x135 pixel
- Thumbnail Image: 75x75 pixel

---

**The easier option (detailed):**

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_filtersMap[$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_filtersMap[$field];
                }
                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
         //$result[] = $product->getData();
           $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

           $result[] = array( // Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids'=> $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'url_path'  =>  $full_product->getImageUrl(),
            // 'product_path' => $full_product->getProductUrl() 
            // you can call $full_product->getData();
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Actually I am an Android Dev And had little knowledge Of PHP(Magneto)...but with the help of few of my colleagues got the Answer Exactly the Same that you have posted here..was going to answer my own Answer.Yours is with more brief Details.Thanks for Your Help.I would use extra knowledge shared by you.Once again Thank you very Much!!

Comment: Thank you @HareshChaudhary ! I just had a little experiences with Magento's API for android. that's why i know about that code. lol. Soon i will ask you about android.

Comment: The above was the output of the first code snippet..in the second one,I don't know the Value of "$product_id"..who to get it ??