# How to include product images in Magento's products list Rest Api

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

I am new to magento and making mobile application of it, for that I am using `REST API`. But in Product list API I want to add at least single image of product so that app will not take much time to load.

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733087/how-to-include-product-images-in-magento-apis-product-list-method-result) 
for `SOAP API` that provided below solution:

```
public function assignedProducts($categoryId, $store = null)
{
    $category = $this->_initCategory($categoryId);

    $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
    $collection = $category->setStoreId($storeId)->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('brand','image','price','description','short_description','name'));
    ($storeId == 0)? $collection->addOrder('position', 'asc') : $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');

    $result = array();
    $type = 'image';
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'position'   => $product->getCatIndexPosition(),
            'brand'      => $product->getData('brand'),
            'price'      => $product->getData('price'),
            'name'      => $product->getData('name'),
            'description'      => $product->getData('description'),
            'short_description'      => $product->getData('short_description'),
            'image_url'  => $product-> getImageUrl() 
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

But I am unable to find anything about `REST API`. I tried to do something in  `protected function _retrieveCollection()` of class `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest.php` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the admin context to get the product collection you will not get image URL links in the response since it uses **Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest_Admin_V1::_retrieveCollection**.

If you are using the customer or guest context you will get 'image_url' for each product which is the standard size image. This is handled in **Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest::_retrieveCollection** via a call to **Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest::_prepareProductForResponse** for each product in the collection. You could extend **Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest::_prepareProductForResponse** and add additional image URLs for 'small_image' and 'thumbnail' if you wanted.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_Api2SessionLogin and https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_Api2SessionAuthAdapter if you are using Mage_Api2 for customer facing APIs. They allow cookie session based usage instead of Oauth tokens. In some cases this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:

In: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest.php

Under the function : _prepareProductForResponse function

**Add the following line to show the image.**

```
 $productData['image_url'] = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
```

Proper way:
Create an custom extension to the API and add the line above in the extension.